# azure storage pricing for sql server in vm

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sql-server

I have created a SQL server 2016 virtual machine.

I have added 6 disks of 1 TB SSD each to my machine.

Is the pricing for each 1 TB disk the same as the premium storage disk (e.g. 148$ per month) or is there another pricing for the disks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the pricing for each 1 TB disk the same as the premium storage disk
>   (e.g. 148$ per month)

Yes, it is right. Only premium storage account supports SSD disk. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-premium-storage#pricing-and-billing).

> Billing for a premium storage disk or blob depends on the provisioned
>   size of the disk or blob. Azure maps the provisioned size (rounded up)
>   to the nearest premium storage disk option.

You select 4 1TB data disk, you need pay for 4 P30 cost(even you don't use them).

Comment: `Is the pricing for each 1 TB disk the same as the premium storage disk` - Should be NO

Comment: @GauravKP The OP uses SSD, not HDD. If the 1 TB disk is HDD disk. The answer is no.